# View object on layer B only when specific object if visible in layer A

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, line, expression

I have a layer "A" with lines and a layer "B" with points.
I have within layer B a field telling for each point to which line it is connected (layer A lines ID).

When I hide some lines of my layer A I would like to automatically hide points linked to those lines (same line ID).

I thought it might be possible within the symbology ?

**Edit 1:**
I would like to see only info off the highlighted item and not the other items located in the same spot but not linked to the line (different attributes)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hide (toggle visibility) your point layer. On the line layer, add an additional symbol layer, set it to `Geometry generator / Point` to symbolize all points here, on the line layer. Use this expression:

```
collect_geometries( overlay_contains ('points', $geometry))
```

*Layer `Points` is invisible, points are created with an additional symbol layer on the line layer - on each line symbol separately. When you hide the red line, the points on it disappear as well:*
[image]

To be able to still use the `Identify Features` tool, you can set the points layer to visible, but use `No Symbology` for rendering. Points are then not visible (only their symbology on the lines layer), but you can still use Identify to check attributes.

[image]

Comment: This work very well for the visualisation part. But for the request part, when I check information with the 'i' tool I still get infos for every points stocked at the same place (many stops point in the exact same spot) and not only the one visible

Comment: I added a solution for that to my answer.

Comment: This solution still not resolve my problem as I have mutiple entities at the same coordinates. I would like info only af the entity visible on the map in this case the one with the same line id

Comment: I don't know exactly how your data looks like and how it is structured. But probably, what you want to do can be done using actions. However, probably you'd better ask a separate question on that because this is another topic and you might get better chances if asked in a question on its own.

Comment: Thanks for you remark, but I think it's still the same question "When I hide some lines of my layer A I would like to automaticaly hide points linked to thoses lines (same line ID)." 
Maybe what's missleading is the terme "hide" as I would like not only those entities to be not visible but also not interactive on the map. Just as if it was unchecked on the layer panel. Do you think I should edit the first post to precise?